create a new column based on config table
there is one dataset which contains flight details like frictionreportdatetime, offsetdistance, offsetdirection, chainage, measuringspeed, cofvalue
in offsetdirection there is data like 9 for chainage from some values now the thing is i need to create a newcolumn with name offsetdirection using config table which looks like with cloumn names runway and oppositerunway with data 9, 14 in runway column and 27, 32 in oppositerunway column first we need to read first row which is 9 from config table which it will chunk the data from main dataset where offsetdirection is 9 then based on case statement it needs to create newoffsetdirection column in main dataset the case statement is like Case when chainage between min(chainage) and max(chainage/2) then 'Runway' when chainage between max(chainage/2) and max(chainage) then 'oppositeRunway' this is the usecase

can you add your code and error you are facing?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
main_data = [
    ("2022-01-01 10:00:00", 100, 9, 50, 200, 0.5),
    ("2022-01-01 11:00:00", 200, 14, 75, 300, 0.6),
    ("2022-01-01 12:00:00", 150, 9, 80, 250, 0.7),
    ("2022-01-01 13:00:00", 300, 27, 120, 400, 0.8),
    ("2022-01-01 14:00:00", 250, 32, 150, 350, 0.9)
]
main_df = spark.createDataFrame(main_data, ["frictionreportdatetime", "offsetdistance", "offsetdirection", "chainage", "measuringspeed", "cofvalue"])
config_data = [(9, 14, 27, 32, 0, 150)]
config_df = spark.createDataFrame(config_data, ["runway", "oppositerunway", "min_chainage_runway", "max_chainage_runway", "min_chainage_opposite", "max_chainage_opposite"])
joined_df = main_df.join(config_df, 
                         (main_df.offsetdirection == config_df.runway) | (main_df.offsetdirection == config_df.oppositerunway),
                         "left")
new_df = joined_df.withColumn("newoffsetdirection",
                               when((col("chainage").between(col("min_chainage_runway"), col("max_chainage_runway") / 2)), "Runway")
                               .when((col("chainage").between(col("max_chainage_runway") / 2, col("max_chainage_runway"))), "oppositeRunway")
                               .when((col("chainage").between(col("min_chainage_opposite"), col("max_chainage_opposite") / 2)), "Runway")
                               .when((col("chainage").between(col("max_chainage_opposite") / 2, col("max_chainage_opposite"))), "oppositeRunway")
                               .otherwise("Other"))  # Default value for unmatched cases
result_df = new_df.select("frictionreportdatetime", "offsetdistance", "offsetdirection", "chainage", "measuringspeed", "cofvalue", "newoffsetdirection")
display(result_df)

Results:
frictionreportdatetime  offsetdistance  offsetdirection chainage    measuringspeed  cofvalue    newoffsetdirection
2022-01-01 10:00:00 100 9   50  200 0.5 Runway
2022-01-01 12:00:00 150 9   80  250 0.7 oppositeRunway
2022-01-01 11:00:00 200 14  75  300 0.6 Runway
2022-01-01 13:00:00 300 27  120 400 0.8 Other
2022-01-01 14:00:00 250 32  150 350 0.9 Other

In the above code, I have created fields such as frictionreportdatetime, offsetdistance, offsetdirection, chainage, measuringspeed, and cofvalue.
config_data contains configuration data defining runway directions and chainage limits.
joined_df is a DataFrame created by joining main_df and config_df on the condition that main_df.offsetdirection matches either config_df.runway or config_df.oppositerunway.
The join type is left, meaning all rows from main_df will be kept, and matched rows from config_df will be added.
new_df is a DataFrame created by adding a new column newoffsetdirection to joined_df.
The column is populated using multiple conditions applied with the when function:

If chainage is between min_chainage_runway and half of max_chainage_runway, it assigns "Runway".
If chainage is between half of max_chainage_runway and max_chainage_runway, it assigns "oppositeRunway".
If chainage is between min_chainage_opposite and half of max_chainage_opposite, it assigns "Runway".
If chainage is between half of max_chainage_opposite and max_chainage_opposite, it assigns "oppositeRunway".
For all other cases, it assigns "Other".

And result_df has the desired columns and a new column newoffsetdirection based on the specified conditions.
